# Implement std::iterator

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Because C++17 deprecates `std::iterator`, I need to implement my own. Turns out it is just an empty struct with some typedefs.

```
template <class Category, class Type, class Diff = ptrdiff_t,
    class Pointer = Type*, class Reference = Type&>
struct iterator {
  typedef Category iterator_catergory;
  typedef Type value_type;
  typedef Diff difference_type;
  typedef Pointer pointer;
  typedef Reference reference;
};

struct dummy_iter : iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, int> {}
```

This works:

```
printf("%d\n", std::is_same<typename dummy_iter::pointer, int*>::value);
```

However, it does not work with `std::iterator_traits`:

```
printf("%d\n", std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<dummy_iter>::pointer, int*>::value);

error: 'pointer' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<dummy_iter>' does not name a type
```

Comment: You don't have to implement your own. `std::iterator` is still in the standard, and every standard library implementation is required to provide it. Deprecation is a warning that something **might** be removed in the future. That doesn't remove it, and it doesn't mean that it will be removed. The C headers have been deprecated since 1998 and they're still alive and kicking and widely used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo. This statement:

```
typedef Category iterator_catergory;
```

Should be this instead:

```
typedef Category iterator_category;
```

The standard specifies that unless `iterator_traits` contains all the required typedefs, it becomes an empty class. See [iterator.traits]/2:

> If Iterator has valid ([temp.deduct]) member types difference_­type,
>   value_­type, pointer, reference, and iterator_­category,
>   iterator_­traits shall have the following as publicly
>   accessible members:
>
> ```
>   using difference_type   = typename Iterator::difference_type;
>   using value_type        = typename Iterator::value_type;
>   using pointer           = typename Iterator::pointer;
>   using reference         = typename Iterator::reference;
>   using iterator_category = typename Iterator::iterator_category;
> ```
>
> Otherwise, iterator_­traits shall have no members by any of
>   the above names.

Comment: Nice job.  You beat me by under a minute. :-)